# SQL Window Functions - filter by specific conditions possible?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

I want to count the number of records partitioned by a group and ordered by a date but with certains conditions, in this case that two column values must both be higher than the current row compared to previous rows.

```
    (
select 'a' grouper,5 num1,55 num2,to_date('01.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') as dt,null as expected_res from dual union all
select 'a' grouper,3 num1,40 num2,to_date('02.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') as dt,1 as expected_res from dual union all
select 'a' grouper,4 num1,100 num2,to_date('03.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') as dt,null as expected_res from dual
    )
select base.* from base order by grouper,dt;
```

| grouper | num1 | num2 | dt | expected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | 55 | 01.01.2022 | null (For this partition there is now previous record order by date) |
| a | 3 | 40 | 02.01.2022 | 1 (For this partition there is a previous record and both num1 and num2 are eacher higher than those of this row |
| a | 4 | 100 | 03.01.2022 | null (For this partition there are two previous records but in the previous row [row2] both nums are lower so i dont want to count this row and for the first row num1 is higher than num1 of this row but num2 is lower, so i dont want to count it |

I know that i can use a corrected subquery for this problem but the performance will be bad due to high amount of data. Is this problem solvable by using window functions?

I would need something like this:

```
count(*) over (partition by grouper order by dt asc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding where num1 AND num2 in window > num1 AND num2 of current row
```

Comment: You can use LAG twice with 1 and 2 as offset in a subquery and do the calculation in the surrounding query (with a CASE...)

Comment: But i have to use a subquery then, so i guess its not possible without one? Atleast i cannot find a solution :)

Comment: The LAG should work in a CASE but putting them in a subquery avoids to have several times the same LAG expression in the query, making it more difficult to read and maintain.

Comment: Do you see any advantage with performance by your suggest solution to using an inequality join? Also could you do a fiddle with the above sample sql to show your solution since i am not sure if i understand your solution correctly, please?

Comment: These [two solutions](https://dbfiddle.uk/7zX-gava) are too slow?

Comment: First of all thanks for your effort!
I think something is not working correctly, as i expect CNT in row[3] to be 0, because in each of the two previous rows num1 AND num2 are not lower than in row[3].
CNT in row[4] (the row with grouper a that you added), i expect to be 3 and not 2, because ALL previous pairs of num1 and num2 are lower than the ones in row[4]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use [MODEL](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm) clause. It is supposed to be fast.

```sql
WITH      -- Sample data
    base AS
        (
            Select 'a' "GROUPER", 5 "NUM1",  55 "NUM2", To_Date('01.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') "DT" From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           3,         40,        To_Date('02.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           4,        100,        To_Date('03.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual
        )

M a i n   S Q L
Select GROUPER, NUM1, NUM2, DT, EXPECTED_RESULT  
From 
    ( Select  ROWNUM "RN",GROUPER, NUM1, NUM2, DT, 0 "EXPECTED_RESULT"
      From    base
      Order By DT 
    )
    MODEL   Partition By (GROUPER)
            Dimension By (RN)
            Measures (NUM1, NUM2, DT,EXPECTED_RESULT)
    RULES   (   EXPECTED_RESULT[ANY] = CASE WHEN CV(RN) = 1 THEN Null 
                                       ELSE 
                                          CASE WHEN NUM1[CV() - 1] > NUM1[CV()] And NUM2[CV() - 1] > NUM2[CV()] THEN 1 END
                                       END 
            )

R e s u l t :
GROUPER       NUM1       NUM2 DT        EXPECTED_RESULT
------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------------
a                5         55 01-JAN-22                 
a                3         40 02-JAN-22               1 
a                4        100 03-JAN-22
```

**Updated**:
The above code compares values with 1 previous row only. If you want to compare values in current row with any of the previous rows and count those that has both values greater than in current row - check the code below. Notice that the sample data is changed a bit.

```sql
WITH
    base AS
        (
            Select 'a' "GROUPER", 5 "NUM1",  57 "NUM2", To_Date('01.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY') "DT" From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           3,         56,        To_Date('02.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           2,         51,        To_Date('03.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           3,         50,        To_Date('04.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual Union All
            Select 'a',           4,         55,        To_Date('05.01.2022','DD.MM.YYYY')      From Dual
        )

Select GROUPER, NUM1, NUM2, DT, EXPECTED_RESULT
From ( Select  ROWNUM "RN", GROUPER, NUM1, NUM2, DT, 0 "EXPECTED_RESULT"
      From    base
      Order By DT 
     )
    MODEL   Partition By (GROUPER)
            Dimension By (RN, NUM1, NUM2)
            Measures (DT, EXPECTED_RESULT)
    RULES   (   EXPECTED_RESULT[ANY, ANY, ANY] = Count(DT)[RN < CV(RN), NUM1 > CV(NUM1), NUM2 > CV(NUM2) ]  )

GROUPER       NUM1       NUM2 DT        EXPECTED_RESULT
------- ---------- ---------- --------- ---------------
a                5         57 01-JAN-22               0 
a                3         56 02-JAN-22               1 
a                2         51 03-JAN-22               2 
a                3         50 04-JAN-22               1 
a                4         55 05-JAN-22               1
```

Comment: This looks very intereting, i didn't know about this feature! It seems to be pretty powerful. Result is as expected, if this is fast, then it seems like a very good solution. I will look deeper into it, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Dizzy2510 Just posted the update that should do the count that you asked for.